Cómo pasar datos de una funcion javascript a un modal?
Esta función recoge los datos de un registro el en objeto data.
var obtener_data_editar = function(tbody, table) {
    $(tbody).on("click", "button.editar", function(){
        var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        console.log(data);
        $('#editarLinea').modal('show');
        $('#id').val(data['id']);
        $('#producto').val(data['producto']);
        $('#nombre').val(data['nombre']);
        $('#cantidad').val(data['cantidad']);
        $('#precio').val(data['precio']);
        $('#importe').val(data['importe']);
    });
};

Después se llama a un modal con elementos  identificados con su etiqueta:
<div class="modal fade" data-bs-theme="light" id="editarLinea" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editarLineaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="<?=base_url(auth()->user()->locale . '/lineas/' . $linea['id'] . '/' . $id); ?>" method="POST" name="editLinea_form" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>    
                <input type="text" id="id" name="id">
                <input type="text" id="producto" name="producto">
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
                <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad">
                <input type="text" id="precio" name="precio">
                <input type="text" id="importe" name="importe">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" style="color: #00FF40;"><i class="bi bi-floppy"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

De esta forma veo los datos en el modal de forma correcta. Pero, para modificar y actualizar los datos, necesito incluirlos en un formulario con una url que me dirija a una función del controlador donde hago el update. Aquí es donde tengo el problema. Tengo que sustituir linea['id'] del action del form por el valor de $('id').val(data['id']); para que la ruta $routes->put('{locale}/lineas/(:num)/(:num)',           'Pedidos::update_linea/$1/$2'); me dirija a la función correcta.

No dupliques preguntas. Basta modificar la pregunta anterior como para que vuelva a revisión y evaluar si debe ser reabierta.

1.- Seleccionas el form que está dentro del modal editarLinea y obtienes el atributo action
const form =  document.querySelector("#editarLinea form");
const oldAction = form.getAttribute("action")

2.- Le haces un split('/') para obtener cada string que se encuentra dentro de un slash. Y modificas el penultimo elemento el cual corresponde al linea['id']
const action_split = oldAction.split("/");
action_split[action_split.length - 2] = data['id']; 

3.- Finalmente unes todo nuevamente usando join("/") y actualizas el atributo action
form.setAttribute("action", action_split.join("/"));


Muy buena solución. Y sencilla. Gracias
